# How can i have more than 255 arguments in Z3py function?

Tags: python, z3, smt, constraint-programming

I would like to kindly ask ,  how to have more than 255 arguments in the Z3 Python function

```
    h1, h2 = Consts('h1 h2', S)
     def fun(h1 , h2):
          return Or(
 And( h1 == cl_4712, h2 == me_1935),
 And( h1 == cl_1871, h2 == me_1935),
 And( h1 == cl_4712, h2 == me_1935),
                   .
                   .
                   .
  And( h1 == cl_1871, h2 == me_6745)
                )
```

Comment: why not put the arguments into some sort of data structure like a dict?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
func(arg1, arg2, arg3)
```

is exactly equivalent to

```
args = (arg1, arg2, arg3)
func(*args)
```

So supply the arguments as a single iterable:

```
Or(*(And(...),...))
```

Or more clearly:

```
conditions = (And(...), ...)
Or(*conditions)
```

Or perhaps you can just supply a generator that produces your conditions:

```
def AndCond(a, b):
    for ....:
        yield And(...)

Or(*AndCond(v1, v2))
```

I would probably have written your code like this:

```
h1, h2 = Consts('h1 h2', S)
def fun(h1 , h2):
    # possibly this should be a set() or frozenset()
    # since logically every pair should be unique?
    h1_h2_and_conds = [
        (cl_4712, me_1935),
        (cl_1871, me_1935),
        (cl_1871, me_6745),
        # ...
    ]
    and_conds = (And(h1==a, h2==b) for a,b in h1_h2_and_conds)
    return Or(*and_conds)
```

Comment: Based on this modification , how can I  retrieve the matched model:

Comment: All this code has the exact same return value as your code, so I don't know what you mean?

Comment: for example , if I have 2 constants x1,x2 , and i want to retrieve the values form the function fun , the model of x1=cl_4712, cl_1871 and the model of x2 = me_1935,me_6745 .. hope it make a sense